# SwiftLint setup with Xcode

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I am using a setup on Xcode that runs the following script for `SwiftLint`

```
if which $PATH/swiftlint >/dev/null; then
$PATH/swiftlint
elif which $HOME/.brew/bin/swiftlint >/dev/null; then
$HOME/.brew/bin/swiftlint
elif which ~/Softwares/homebrew/bin/swiftlint >/dev/null; then
~/Softwares/homebrew/bin/swiftlint
else
echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

I am unable to use  `pods` or brew.

To make `SwiftLint` available I added the following to my path by using 
vim `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/me/Documents/SwiftLint
```

and I can now access `SwiftLint` everywhere through the command line.

However, Xcode still displays the message that SwiftLint is not installed.

I can't use another method to install Swiftlint or change the script. I guess there is a problem with my export path - what is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When running scripts, `.bash_profile` will not be considered. I would just prepend your script like this:

```sh
if test -d "${HOME}/Documents/SwiftLint"; then
  PATH="${HOME}/Documents/SwiftLint:${PATH}"
fi

export PATH

if ! which swiftlint >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint" >&2
fi
```

Comment: Hi, Is this solution work on both intel and M1 Mac?

Answer (score 1):

You could just export the path to system-wide variables.

Steps to do

1. open Terminal
2. run command  `open .zshrc`
3. add `export PATH="${HOME}/Documents/SwiftLint:${PATH}"`
4. Save and close